# SQL: Output duplicate names but show all all appt dates and order by latest appt date

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
ID | Name | ApptDate
===+======+=========
1  |Adam  | 2017-07-25
1  |Adam  | 2017-05-23
1  |Adam  | 2017-08-25
2  |Paul  | 2017-07-25
2  |Paul  | 2016-03-20
2  |Paul  | 2018-08-25
3  |Zach  | 2018-09-25
3  |Zach  | 2016-01-01
```

output should be like this

```
ID | Name | ApptDate
===+======+=========
3  |Zach  | 2018-09-25
3  |Zach  | 2016-01-01
1  |Adam  | 2017-08-25
1  |Adam  | 2017-07-25
1  |Adam  | 2017-05-23
2  |Paul  | 2017-08-25
2  |Paul  | 2017-07-25
2  |Paul  | 2017-03-20
```

I trying to get the above output.

thanks

Comment: _I trying to get the above output._ Where are you trying that? Post code...

Comment: have you tried `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ApptDate DESC` ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to filter to *only* show duplicated names, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
 a.ID, a.Name, a.ApptDate
FROM table a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT b.Name FROM table b WHERE a.Name = b.Name GROUP BY b.Name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY a.Name, a.ApptDate DESC
```